# Java Ternary operator syntax

Tags: java, syntax, ternary-operator

I have the following piece of code. This is how I understand it.

In the first case, the ternary operator returns the value of `y` because `x=4` and the print statement prints `5`, as expected.

In the 2nd case, the ternary operator first assigns the value of y to x and then returns that value. Again, it prints 5, as expected.

In the 3rd case, the ternary operator has `x=y` to the left of the : and  `x=z` to the right of the `:`. I would expect this to behave much like the 2nd case. However, this statement does not even compile.

Any help in understanding this will be much appreciated.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 4;
        int y = 5;
        int z = -1;

        x = (x == 4) ? y : z;        // compiles and runs fine
        System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);

        x = (x == 4) ? x = y : z;    // compiles and runs fine
        System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);

        x = (x == 4) ? x = y : x = z;  // Does not compile
        System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Either `x = (x==4)?(x=y):(x=z);` or `x = (x==4)?x=y:(x=z);` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assignment has lower precedence than a ternary expression, so this expression:

```
(x==4)?x=y:x = z;
```

can be thought of as:

```
((x==4)?x=y:x) = z;
```

Which obviously won't compile because you can't assign a value to something that isn't a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Add parenthesis to control the order of evaluation

```
x = (x == 4) ? (x = y) : (x = z); // Does compile.
```

**Note** the above is equivalent to

```
if (x == 4) {
    x = (x = y);
} else {
    x = (x = z);
}
```

Which will (as a side effect) of assigning a value to `x` assign the value assigned to `x` to `x`. In other words, your ternary is equivalent to

```
x = (x == 4) ? y : z;
```

**or**

```
if (x == 4) {
   x = y;
} else {
   x = z;
}
```

The ternary is specified in [JLS-15.25. Conditional Operator `? :`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).